# MySQL - Generate rows based on results only when needed

Tags: mysql, random, rows

I've created a view on MySQL which produces random results like this:

**SELECT word1, word2, word3 FROM view_name ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 50**

```
word1 | word2 | word3 |
------+-------+-------+
foo2  | bar2  | baz2  |
foo1  | bar1  | baz1  |
foo3  | bar3  | baz3  |
```

I need to find a way to randomly create, from these 3 rows, another 47 rows to reach the "limit".

The query will also be applied to similar views (with more than 50 rows), but in that case, I still need the limit set to 50 max (ignoring the repeat process and returning rows from select).

Is it possible? How could I do it?

***UPDATE***
   Sorry, I'll try to explain better. I have this scenario:

- Im generating some views with the same kind of query, but different WHERE clauses.
- The results have the the same columns. The difference will be the number of rows returned.
- Some views returns more than 50 rows, others returns less.
- The goal is to return exactly 50 rows. If the view returns less then 50, I need to generate the remaining rows. If the view returns more than 50 row, it will return 50 only.

  E.g.:
- View1 returns 3 rows. I need to generate 47 rows to return 50 rows.
- View2 returns 55 rows. I dont need to generate rows, just want to LIMIT to 50 rows.
- View3 returns 25 rows. I need to generate 25 rows ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try something like this:

```
SELECT final.tempval1, final.tempval2, final.tempval3
FROM (
  SELECT temptable1.tempval4 AS tempval1, temptable5.word2 AS tempval2, temptable6.word3 AS tempval3
  FROM (
    SELECT temptable2.word1 AS tempval4, temptable2.word2 AS tempval5, temptable2.word3 AS tempval6
    FROM view_name temptable2
    LEFT JOIN view_name temptable3 ON temptable2.word1 = temptable3.word1
    LEFT JOIN view_name temptable4 ON temptable3.word2 = temptable4.word2 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 50 offset 3
  ) temptable1    
  LEFT JOIN view_name temptable5 ON temptable1.tempval4 = temptable5.word1
  LEFT JOIN view_name temptable6 ON temptable5.word2 = temptable6.word2
  LIMIT 0, 50
) final
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 50
```

Took me a while to figure out exactly what you're looking for and I'm still not sure if I understood correctly so if it doesn't work feel free to let me know.

Comment: I've tried you code and it is generating 47 rows. I've removed the offset and changed the RAND() to the "final" table and it is now working, but I need to test with other views. Thanks! May I edit your post and set it as answer? Don't know exactly how this works on stackoverflow...

Comment: Oh OK... I thought you wanted only 47: `I need to find a way to randomly create, from these 3 rows, another 47 rows to reach the "limit".` OOPS OK I just read your update... Anyway, if the system will allow you to edit the answer, feel free. I'll edit it right now though so if I misunderstood what you changed, let me know. :)